# Firebase database wasn't reachable. How often does it happen?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

1. Each of failed requests was stalled for 10 seconds, so for 40 seconds my app couldn't reach the Firebase database.
2. I tried to open https://console.firebase.google.com/ and I couldn't react it either.

While https://status.firebase.google.com/ said that database is in normal operations. And any other web pages I opened worked normally.

Is it normal and how often does it happen?
[image]

[image]

Comment: it can be related to your slow internet connection or temporary network connectivity issue at your side.

Answer (score 0):

If you think Firebase has downtime, always check the [Firebase status dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/) as you did.

You'll see there that we regularly post for interruptions on the individual database servers. But the time of the last status update doesn't match with your post, so it is unlikely you were seeing an outage.

Since you also couldn't reach the console, which hasn't had any reported outage in over a week, it is much more likely that there was an interruption between your machine and the Firebase servers.